# How can I insert a Print button that prints a table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i have an asp.net mvc project. there is an index page with extension cshtml. and when i generated it shows to me on browser a page contain title, buttons, table and footer.
i want to add a button to print just the table not all the page.
i add in the layout:

```html
<link id="ctl00_Link1" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
```

and in the end of index page:

```html
<div class="line-btn ">
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$Index" value="print" onclick="window.print();return false;" id="ctl00_MainContent_Button1" class="btn fl btn-print">

            </div>
```

but it still doesn't work and print all the index page!

Comment: The id "ctl00_MainContent_Button1" is for asp.net webform not mvc. The tag is not correct

Comment: ok, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using following code. Add following in your `index.cshtml` page:

```
<div class="line-btn">
    <input type="submit" value="print" onclick="PrintOnlyTable()" class="btn fl btn-print">
</div>

<script>
    function PrintOnlyTable() {
        var HTML = $("html");
        var cln = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
        HTML.html($("table"));
        window.print();
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = cln;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```